# Plot 3 numeric variables against date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 3 numeric values against year in Python and it is bringing back a blank plot. I have tried multiple variation of code but it still doesn't work. The table I have attached[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItSv6.png) is the data I am trying to plot. What I am looking at creating is a line graph with years on the x axis, and the total number of deaths  for synthetic, heroin and cocaine against the y axis

Basically trying to create this but within python:
[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYAyY.png)

I have used the below code and it fails to work. (NB: the year_column = 'Year ' is correct as the column within my csv file has a space after year).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Overdose_data_1999-2021 1.19.231.csv'))

print(data)

year_column = 'Year '
variable1_column = 'Synthetic Opioids other than Methadone (primarily fentanyl)'
variable2_column = 'Heroin'
variable3_column = 'Cocaine'


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.plot(data[year_column], data[variable1_column], label='Synthetic Opioids')
plt.plot(data[year_column], data[variable2_column], label='Heroin')
plt.plot(data[year_column], data[variable3_column], label='Cocaine')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Plot of Overdose Deaths Over Years')
plt.legend()

plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

To load a subset of data, you can do

```
data = {'year': (1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006),
 'total': (16849, 17415, 19394, 23518, 25785, 27424, 29813, 34425),
 'syntetic opioids': (730, 782, 957, 1295, 1400, 1664, 1742, 2707),
 'heroine': (1960, 1842, 1779, 2089, 2080, 1878, 2009, 2088),
 'cocaine': (3822, 3544, 3833, 4599, 5199, 5443, 6208, 7448)}
```

but it's uncertain if `data` in my script is corresponding because of the commas problem noticed by Jared.

Comment: Please share data as text, not as an image. Suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Apologies, please see below as text:                                                                                       Year,   Total Overdose Deaths, Synthetic Opioids other than Methadone (primarily fentanyl), Heroin, Cocaine
1999, 16,849,  730, 1,960, 3,822
2000, 17,415,  782, 1,842, 3,544
2001, 19,394,  957, 1,779, 3,833
2002, 23,518,                1,295, 2,089, 4,599
2003, 25,785,  1,400, 2,080, 5,199
2004, 27,424,  1,664, 1,878, 5,443
2005, 29,813,                1,742, 2,009, 6,208
2006, 34,425,  2,707, 2,088, 7,448

Comment: This information should be included in your post not as a comment. Please edit your post to include that.

Comment: Also, commas in numbers does not work in a CSV file. Are you sure that's exactly how your CSV looks?

Comment: To stress Jared's [last remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215103/plot-3-numeric-variables-against-date/78215564#comment137891191_78215103), if you REALLY have commas as thousands separators in your CSV, then when you read it using Pandas, it is converted to garbage

Comment: You write `it fails to work`, but that doesn't tell us much. What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? A crash? An unexpected output? ...?  You could try `thousands=','` in `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: `ax = data.plot(x='year', figsize=(10, 8))`